# Unmarshal json array into struct array

Tags: mysql, go, unmarshalling, sqlx, gqlgen

I'm using `Mysql 8`. I'm also utilizing `99designs/gqlgen` to autogenerate the structs based on the GraphQL schema.
I was to re-use the same structs when scanning MySql responses. And on top of that, while prototyping, I want to have some JSONs in my table.
So the struct is:

```
type CustomizedItemInput struct {
    Sku              string                 `json:"sku"`
    Name             string                 `json:"name"`
    Skus             []*CustomizedComponent `json:"skus"`
    ...
```

Since storing(providing `Value()`) is simpler I managed to store Skus into DB as a top-level JSON successfully. Looks like this:

```
[{"sku": "123", "position": "LEFT"}, {"sku": "456", "position": "RIGHT"}]
```

Now, how do I get this value out of DB and back into a array of pointers inside the struct without much hustle?
Of course, ideally it should be done without changing the underlying struct because it's autogenerated.

**UPDATE:**
Adding debugging information. I need to read a DB row into CustomizedItemView which basically mirrors CustomizedItemInput from above:

```
type CustomizedItemView struct {
    Sku              string                     `json:"sku"`
    Name             string                     `json:"name"`
    Skus             []*CustomizedComponentView `json:"skus"`
    ...
```

Of course, when I say "without hustle" I mean having the DB row extracted into a struct seamlessly. I can add `map[string]interface{}{}` with all bells and whistles and get the value. But I want to have it neat, like:

```
    var storedCustItem = model.CustomizedItemView{}
    err := udb.Get(&storedCustItem, database.SelectCustomizationQuery, userID, custItem.Sku, createdAt)
```

The error I get is:

```
2020/10/10 20:38:24 sql: Scan error on column index 8, name "skus": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]*model.CustomizedComponentView
```

(8 because I removed some fields for the example).
The main problem is that I can't create `Scan()` for an unnamed type. I have created wrappers for `Value()` because my inserts are more verbose and I do type conversion with the wrapper type in them:

```
type CustomizedComponentsIn []*CustomizedComponent
...
func (customizedComponents CustomizedComponentsIn) Value() (driver.Value, error)
...
tx.MustExec(database.SaveCustomizationCommand,
        custItem.Sku,
        custItem.Name,
        model.CustomizedComponentsIn(custItem.Skus)
...
```

,which is Ok for inserts because there will be some values that do not belong to the input struct.
But I hoped to at least get the value scanned into a View struct automatically.

Comment: You can either change the type of the `Skus` field to a *named* slice type, then have this named slice type implement the `sql.Scanner` interface. If you can't change the type of the `Skus` field then you could write a wrapper type that implements the interface or a conversion function and invoke this this conversion function or use this wrapper type whenever you are scanning the `Skus` field, which requires that you explicitly enumerate the fields when scanning the rows.

Comment: @mkopriva, I have added more detail to the question. Can you take a look? I'm relatively new to go, so Im not sure I get it what you mean by the wrapper. I see an example from your answer, but it does imply changing the generated struct.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the type of the `Skus` field, the common approach would be to declare a slice type that implements the `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer` interfaces and use that instead of the unnamed `[]*CustomizedComponent` type.

For example:

```
type CustomizedItemInput struct {
    Sku  string                   `json:"sku"`
    Name string                   `json:"name"`
    Skus CustomizedComponentSlice `json:"skus"`
    // ...
}

type CustomizedComponentSlice []*CustomizedComponent

// Value implements driver.Valuer interface.
func (s CustomizedComponentSlice) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(s)
}

// Scan implements sql.Scanner interface.
func (s *CustomizedComponentSlice) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    var data []byte
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        data = []byte(v)
    case []byte:
        data = v
    default:
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, s)
}
```

---

If you *can't* change type of the `Skus` field you will have to explicitly convert the field during scanning.

For example, given the above named slice type, you could do something like this:

```
v := new(CustomizedItemView)
row := db.QueryRow("SELECT sku, name, skus FROM customized_item_view WHERE sku = ? LIMIT 1", sku)
err := row.Scan(
    &v.Sku,
    &v.Name,
    // do the conversion here, and any other place where you're scanning Skus... 
    (*CustomizedComponentSlice)(&v.Skus),
)
if err != nil {
   return err
}
fmt.Println(v.Skus) // result
```